# Can not append to file.readline (Attribute Error) - I expected it to be a list

Tags: python, attributeerror

How can I store another value in the pre-existing list `todos`?

When I try to store the new datum, I have the following error

```bash
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\Coding\python projects\project 1\add_or_show.py", line 11, in <module>
        todos.append(todo)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`
```

And here it is my code

```
while True:
    action = input("what action you want add or show or exit: ")
    match action:
        case 'add':
            todo = input("Enter the name of a student: ") + '\n'

            file = open('pyt.txt', 'r')
            todos = file.readline()
            file.close()

            todos.append(todo)

            file = open('pyt.txt', 'w')
            file.writelines(todos)

        case 'show':
            for ind, expand in enumerate(todos):
                index = ind + 1
                print(f"{index}   -   {expand}")
            print("The length of Class is: ", len(todos))
        case 'exit':
            print("\n\nyour program exit succaessfully\n\nBye Bye!!!")
            break
        case 'edit':
            num = int(input('Enter number which you want to edit'))
            num_n = num-1
            edt = todos[num_n]
            print(edt)
            put = ('Enter the word you want instead of', edt, ': ')
            newedt = input(put)
            todos[num_n] = newedt
            print("Thanks!, Entry edited Successfilly")

        case _:
            print('Invalid action, please write add or show or exit')
```

Comment: You redefined `todos` with `todos = file.readline()`; it's no longer a list, it's now the line of a file

Comment: You probably wanted `readlines()` (note the `s` at the end)

Answer (score 2):

try use this

```
todos = file.readlines()
```

`file.readlines()` is a method of the built-in Python file object that reads all the lines of the specified file and returns them as a list of strings.

`file.readline()` is a method of the built-in Python file object that reads a single line of the specified file and returns it as a string.